# Is it possible to run two instances of crond each with its separate cron file?

Tags: cron

How to run two instances of crond with different cronjob files?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Maybe, but it's a bit pointless. Maybe you can explain why you think you need it?

Comment: Because the contents of the cron file are as a whole displayed through a webpage and i want to keep all the other jobs except my WiFI schedules in the cron file.Really it would be quite helpful to me.Thnx

Comment: You do not really want to do this. If you do it will cause problems. `crontab` lists/manages jobs per user. Why not create a new user to store the wifi (or non-wifi) jobs? It's not a good idea to try  subvert the service.

Comment: Why are you displaying your crontab through a webpage? (Yes, I'll continue to ask why, until you explain what you are trying to achieve. Whatever it is, there will be a better way, I promise.)

Comment: This is a router so the automatic ON/OFF schedules should be displayed via webpage ,now my only feasible course according to the feedback recieved is to format my file before display or use cron and anacron at the same time.Please see below....thnx anyways Lennart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** NO IT'S NOT POSSIBLE ***

But a possible workaround could be setup Anacron and run the two processes in parallel.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron

Install anacron

```
$ sudo apt-get install anacron
```

Create your anacrontab following: 
http://linux.die.net/man/5/anacrontab

Test your anacrontab file config:

```
anacron -T [-t anacrontab]

-t some_anacrontab Use specified anacrontab, rather than the default
-T Anacrontab testing.
```

**AT THE END:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
$ sudo /etc/init.d/anacron restart
```

The two process should run in parallel.

If this is your need:

> "Because the contents of the cron file are as a whole displayed
>   through a webpage and i want to keep all the other jobs except my WiFI
>   schedules in the cron file.Really it would be quite helpful to me."

then just put what you want to hide in the webpage in the first n lines and then show on the webpage starting from row n+1... it's much better than interfere with crond number of processes."

Additional guide enough to configure anacron? 
http://www.tuxradar.com/content/automate-linux-cron-and-anacron

**Note that:**
Anyway... Anacron's mission is to guarantee that those daily, weekly and monthly activities do actually occur, assuming only that the computer was switched on at some point during the day (or week, or month). Anacron is not concerned with ensuring that activities occur at some precise time.

Comment: can you please write a whole command i am not clear whether u instruct me to use anacrontab or crontab @Madthew

Comment: If this is your need: "Because the contents of the cron file are as a whole displayed through a webpage and i want to keep all the other jobs except my WiFI schedules in the cron file.Really it would be quite helpful to me." then just put what you want to hide in the webpage in the first n lines and then show on the webpage starting from row n+1... it's much better than interfere with crond number of processes.

Comment: I modified the answer trying to be more clear on what you could do as a workaround. Is that enough? Thanks mate.

Comment: Depends , I'll try all the approaches one being formatting while display and the other being yours.Do you know anything about fcron somebody from SO told me about it but the manual doesnt specify whether my req. will be there...!!! @Madthew

Answer (score 0):

Hurmm... no it is not possible, it looks like cron has its configuration path hardcoded in the binary. But why would you want to have multiple cron instances and configurations ?

Comment: Because the contents of the cron file are as a whole displayed through a webpage and i want to keep all the other jobs except my WiFI schedules in the cron file.Really it would be quite helpful to me.Thnx @zmo

Comment: then you could use comments to split your crontab files in several parts. Don't forget to keep it simple! One thing for one task, if you make several instances of cron (or anacron) you're not in the unix philosophy.

Comment: another solution would be to make all the system critical stuff (like the wifi schedules) in root's crontab, and all your "public" stuff in /etc/crontab (or in another user's crontab)

Comment: or simply, grep out all tasks made by the root user in /etc/crontab, before generating your webpage out of your crontab. See, there are many ways to do it ;-)

Comment: yeah that only seems feasible thnx..

Answer (score 0):

Yes i used the cron and anacron combination and it works like a charm.
Thnx @Madthew